# PHP - Search multidimensional array for matches and return array key

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sitename] => newsite
            [sitelink] => link1
            [tosite] => testsite
            [tolink] => ABCD
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sitename] => newsite
            [sitelink] => link2
            [tosite] => secondsite
            [tolink] => 1234
        )

)
```

I need the ability to search the array for entries where `sitename` is set and `sitelink` is either `link1` or `link2`

So if the search determines the sitename is set and the sitelink = link1 then it would return the id 0

If the search find the sitename is set and the sitelink = link2 then it would return the id 3

I was hoping to create a function similar to:
`arraysearch ('link1', $myarray);`

The function would search $myarray, checking only entries where sitename is set, doesn't matter what to and sitelink is the value from the search. eg: link1

Normally there are hundreds of entries in the array.

is there any way to do this ?

This is where I got to testing.

```
function myfunction($array, $site,  $value)
{
   foreach($array as $key => $newarr)
   {
      if ( $newarr[$site] === $value )
         return $key;
   }
   return false;
}

echo myfunction($sites, 'sitelink', 'link1');
```

This sort of works but it doesn't check if sitename is set..

Thanks

Comment: Show your current code

Comment: You say _search this for the sitename and sitelink_ but then say _if sitename is set_?  What does that mean?

Comment: I don't have any code for this as yet as I've no idea how to do it..  I've just updated the original question hopefully with a better explanation..

Comment: Go with `array_filter`, implement the check of the conditions you formulated in the callback function. That will get you the array reduced to the matching element(s), you can then get the keys of those afterwards.

Comment: Sample of where I got to added to question

Comment: "This sort of works but it doesn't check if sitename is set.." - So...check if sitename is set before calling the function would seem logical?

Comment: Thanks I've added a check to see if the name is set and this does now seem to be workiing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myfunction($array, $site,  $value)
{
   foreach($array as $key => $newarr)
   {
      if ( $newarr[$site] === $value && isset( $newarr['sitename'] ) )
         return $key;
   }
   return false;
}

echo myfunction($sites, 'sitelink', 'link1');
```